# How do you use JSONUtility to read an object with hypens in the keys?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm using [JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) to parse input from an external source. Here's an example json payload.

```
{
    "test": "data",
    "the-problem": "uh oh"
}
```

My problem is working out how to get "the-problem" to go into a field. You can't use hyphens for identifiers in C# - so I can't create a matching object structure for that data to get parsed into.

```
[Serializable]
public class Structure {
    public string test;
    public string theProblem;  // You can't use "the-problem" - see the problem?
}
```

Unfortunately, the Unity docs don't talk about this issue.

Is there a way to mark a field (perhaps with an attribute?) in such a way as to override the name used for serialisation/deserialisation purposes? Preferably without relying on third-party libraries as this unity project targets opengl which doesn't always play well with them.

Comment: have you tried newtonsoftjson third party libary it allow to decorate [jsonproperty(name="the-problem")] below this you can declare property of class

Comment: I've been trying to avoid third party libraries - this unity project targets opengl which doesn't always play well with them. But I'll keep that in mind if no-one has a more native way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity (WebGL compatible):

There is an open-source version called Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity released by jilleJr available on [GitHub here](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity) that is a fork of the Newtonsoft.Json repository and maintained especially to work with Unity, including WebGL.

It can be installed through the Unity Package Manager (UPM) following these steps (taken directly from the docs [found here](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Installation-via-UPM))

- Open /Packages/manifest.json, add scope for jillejr, then add the package in the list of dependencies.

```
{
  "scopedRegistries": [
    {
      "name": "Packages from jillejr",
      "url": "https://npm.cloudsmith.io/jillejr/newtonsoft-json-for-unity/",
      "scopes": ["jillejr"]
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jillejr.newtonsoft.json-for-unity": "12.0.201",

    // ...
  }
}
```

- To update the package Open the Package Manager UI Window > Package Manager
- Followed by pressing the update button on the jillejr.newtonsoft.json-for-unity package

Using this package I created the following scripts:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    readonly string jsonInput = "{\"test\": \"data\",\"the-problem\": \"uh oh\"}";//Notice the dash in 'the-problem'
    public Text sampleText; 
    void Start()
    {
        LoadNewtonsoft jsonObject = LoadNewtonsoft.FromJson(jsonInput);

        sampleText.text = jsonObject.test + " " + jsonObject.theProblem;
    }
}
```

and

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class LoadNewtonsoft : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string test;
    [JsonProperty("the-problem")]
    public string theProblem; // Notice that we don't have a dash here

    public static LoadNewtonsoft FromJson(string textJson)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoadNewtonsoft>(textJson);
    }
}
```

Which when build for WebGL gives the following output:
[image]

---

## A method without external dependencies:

*Please note that this solution is focused on making it work **without** using external libraries (as the OP wishes to avoid these) like NewtonSoft as suggested in the other answer/comments, and is by far not the cleanest and most likely not the most performant solution.*

The idea is to go through your json text and find any occurrence of "-" (hyphen) using regex, and replace this with something that is allowed in a C# variable name (In my example i'll replace it with the word "HYPHEN") when parsing from text to an object.

```cs
private static Regex hyphenSymbolPattern = new Regex("[-]");
private static string ReplaceSymbolHyphenForTextHyphen(string json) => hyphenSymbolPattern.Replace(json, "HYPHEN");
```

And doing the opposite when going from a json object to a json string, replacing the word "HYPHEN" with an actual hyphen symbol "-"

```cs
//You can replace "HYPHEN" with whatever you want, just remember that the variable you want to match must also have this word at the place of the "-"
private static Regex hyphenTextpattern = new Regex("(HYPHEN)");
private static string ReplaceTextHyphenForHyphenSymbol(string json) => hyphenTextpattern.Replace(json, "-");
```

Which results in the following output:
[image: Program's output in the Unity console]

**Caveat**
Now there is still one problem with the current implementation, and that is that it doesn't discriminate between a property's name and data, and replaces *all* occurances of "-". Meaning having "uh-oh" as data also turns into "uhHYPHENoh".
[image: Data also gets "-" replaced by "HYPHEN"]

However this can of course also be fixed by adding a regex/function that checks if the previous match is a property name or data, but I think that is outside the scope of this question.

For completeness here is the entire code used for my example:

```cs
//LoadJson.cs
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    readonly string jsonInput = "{\"test\": \"data\",\"the-problem\": \"uh oh\"}";

    void Start()
    {
        TestJson json = TestJson.FromJson(jsonInput);
        Debug.LogFormat("Parsed json object- test: {0}, the-problem: {1}", json.test, json.theHYPHENproblem);

        TestJson.ToJson(json);
    }
}
```

```cs
//TestJson.cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class TestJson
{
    public string test;
    public string theHYPHENproblem;

    private static Regex hyphenTextpattern = new Regex("(HYPHEN)"); 
    private static Regex hyphenSymbolPattern = new Regex("[-]");


    public static TestJson FromJson(string jsonText)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Input JsonText: {0}", jsonText);
        jsonText = ReplaceSymbolHyphenForTextHyphen(jsonText);
        Debug.LogFormat("Replaced jsonText: {0}", jsonText);
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<TestJson>(jsonText);
    }

    public static void ToJson(TestJson jsonObj)
    {
        var jsonText = JsonUtility.ToJson(jsonObj);
        jsonText = ReplaceTextHyphenForHyphenSymbol(jsonText);
        Debug.LogFormat("Serialized from object Json text: {0}", jsonText);
    }

    private static string ReplaceTextHyphenForHyphenSymbol(string json) => hyphenTextpattern.Replace(json, "-");
    private static string ReplaceSymbolHyphenForTextHyphen(string json) => hyphenSymbolPattern.Replace(json, "HYPHEN");
}
```

As you can see this does require you to name your hyphened variables something like `string fooHYPHENBar` or `bool isHYPHENThisHYPHENReal`, which admittedly isn't really nice for readability or overall cleanliness when calling to these variables (On second thought replacing `-` with `_`instead of "HYPHEN" would probably work and not be horrible). But it doesn't require any changes in your json (like removing all occurrences of hyphens and renaming it to `theproblem`, i'm sure you have reasons for wanting to including the hyphens).

---

## Using Newtonsoft.json (no WebGL):

Alternatively if you want to try using a third party lib that can do all of this for you in a way cleaner way I would recommend using [NewtonSoft json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). you can install it using the NuGet package manager (We have since found out that this **does not** work for WebGL, but **will** work for most other platforms).

To import it into Unity:

- navigate to `Tools > NuGet package manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` inside visual studio. This will open up the NuGet Package manager.
- Under `browse` Newtonsoft will most likely be the first option, if not you can search for it using the search bar.
- Select the package and on the right side check the [ ] Project checkbox to install the entire package
- Hit Install.

Alternatively you can use the NuGet Command Line

- Under `Tools > NuGet package manager > Package manager console`
- Run the command `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.3`

Or use [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity) as DerHugo pointed out in the comments (Not that I have never used NuGetForUnity personally, but I have heard that it works well)

Note that *by default* this will place the package **outside** of the `/Assets/` folder. This is a bit tricky as it sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't work (I think it has to do with either VS or Unity not being able to find the package outside the `/Assets/` directory). Especially on WebGL this might pose a problem.

To fix this we will move the package to inside the `/Assets/` folder, where we are sure that Unity/VS can find it.

- Navigate to the installed package (the location will be something like `C:\<user>\<PathToProjectFolder>\YourProject\Packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3`
- Copy/Cut the folder
- Navigate to your assets folder and create a folder `\Plugins\` if it doesn't exist yet (`C:\<user>\<PathToProjectFolder>\YourProject\Assets\Plugins\`
- Paste the Newtonsoft.Json.xx.x.x in the plugins folder.
- If Copied in step 1 be sure to remove the plugin at the old location so it isn't in your project twice.

You can now use the Newtonsoft library by including the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace.

This gives the functionality to use [`JsonPropertyName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) to overwrite a variables property name, example from the docs:

```cs
Videogame starcraft = new Videogame
{
    Name = "Starcraft",
    ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1)
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(starcraft, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);
// {
//   "name": "Starcraft",
//   "release_date": "1998-01-01T00:00:00"
// }
```

And also allows you to use the Newtonsoft (de)serializer, which is a lot more powerful than Unity's `JsonUtility` with a lot more options, basic example from [the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm):

```cs
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

Comment: It's definitely cutting the cake with a shotgun - but it'll keep it mind as a fallback option.

Comment: I had a go with newtonsoft - and while it works in the editor, as soon as I export to webgl I get a "NotSupportedException". If you work out a trick let me know, otherwise I think it's not an option unfortunately.

Comment: I had a look around, and I'm not seeing that option... I'm assuming it'd be in player settings?

Comment: I switched to 4.x a while ago for "dynamic" support. I guess that means I'm going to have to fall back to your primitive solution :( I really appreciate you trying though.

Comment: @Shadow check the top of my answer, There is a package called `Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity` that I tried out just now and that worked even in WebGL for me. I've added the necessary information and where to find it.

Comment: We seem to have a winner! May I recommend clearing the other solutions from your answer? It'll make it more concise for those who come across similar issues in the future.

Comment: @Shadow I had also considered doing that, but ultimate decided against it. Mostly because think (as it is) it does a better job at canonically answering the question "how to use hyphens in json with Unity", and giving alternative options in case someone doesn't want to rely on third party libs, a fork, or just doesn't need WebGL support. I have added some clearer headers though to distinct between the different options.

Comment: If you're keeping the string replace solution around - it might be worth warning that it'll nuke all `-` characters in the message (at least I think it will, I haven't actually tried it) which change values as well as keys, as well as cause syntax errors if there are any negative numbers in the data.

Comment: @Shadow Yep that information is already included under the **caveat** section